# Comparing dates doesn't work if month is different

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare 4 date fields in my access Database and set the date difference between the latest value and adatum into parkdauer. It works fine for any rows in which the dates are during the same month.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Steuerungsboard 
          SET parkdauer = DateDiff('d', [kspausgang], [adatum]) 
          WHERE FORMAT(kspausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy') >= FORMAT( iausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy') 
             And FORMAT( kspausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy') >= FORMAT( aausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy') 
             And FORMAT( kspausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy') >= FORMAT( gausgang, 'dd/MM/yyyy');"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, FailonError
```

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Storing a calculated value is against Normalisation. Why doing that, instead of creating a query with the calculated value ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove all those `FORMAT` things and this will run fine.

The problem with FORMAT is you're actually comparing dates alphabetically, and that's wrong for numerous reasons.

```
"UPDATE Steuerungsboard 
          SET parkdauer = DateDiff('d', [kspausgang], [adatum]) 
          WHERE kspausgang >=  Nz(iausgang) 
             And  kspausgang >=  Nz(aausgang) 
             And  kspausgang >=  Nz(gausgang);"
```

Comment: Without the Formats it doesn't update any fields. This is actually how I had it to begin with.

Comment: That's the valid way to do it, assuming these are all valid date fields. You can go for alphabetical comparison if you change your format to `'YYYY/MM/DD'`, but there probably is an underlying issue if my approach didn't work, and you're better off tracking that down.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you have any Idea as to what the underlying issue could be? They are all Date fields, although they can be NULL. And of course they would have to start with Year if they are being compared Alphabetically, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Nulls are a relevant issue. How do you want to handle these? In my current answer, if one of the columns is null, the comparison evaluates to false. I can easily modify this to make the comparison evaluate to true. I usually troubleshoot by turning it into a normal select query, outputting all the fields, and if I don't get desired results, removing the `WHERE` criteria and adding them back one by one.

Comment: If the value it compares against is NULL it should always be bigger than NULL, which I think is the default behavior. I might investigate with a Select and a View if I have time next to my other work.

Comment: @Nicholas Nope, Null is an unknown value. Any comparison against Null will evaluate to Null which is handled as False, and this behavior can't be changed (other than modifying the query). You can check this by querying `SELECT IIF(Null < 1, "True", "False"), IIF(Null > 1, "True", "False"), IIF(Null = 0, "True", "False")`. This will return `False, False, False`

Comment: That's the problem then, because at least one of the Fields is NULL in all rows.

Comment: See the current edit. You can just use `Nz`, that replaces `Null` with either `""` when being compared to a string, or `0` when being compared to something else. When being compared to a date, `0` is then cast to `30-12-1899 00:00:00`